What is the Dispersion Reticle in The Finals?
In The Finals, there’s a section in the crosshair tab where you can customise a “Dispersion Reticle”.
Am I to assume this indicates bullet spread accuracy? It widens when you move, and shrinks when you’re not, so I assume so. It also shrinks a lot when you’re crouching, so does that mean you’re even more accurate than you would be otherwise?

Yes, the dispersion is directly related to what your character is doing. Moving while shooting is a lot less acurate than shooting during crouching.

How do you know this?

Besides what’s “common sense”, I mean.

Common sense and in-game experience.

@Daemons I believe CounterStrike, and probably several other games, uses "dynamic crosshair" to refer to the same thing. "Dispersion Reticle" might be exclusive to The Finals.
